# Probability - Bayes' Rule/Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a deck of 52 cards, ordered such that A > K > Q > ⋯ > 3 > 2. Player A randomly picks one first, then player B randomly picks one out of the rest. What is the probability that player A’s card is greater than player B’s?

I used used the Bayes' rule of total probabilities and got an answer of P(A>B) = 0.47 but I am not quite sure that I approached the problem correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are ties possible or do you also rank the suits?  In either case,  symmetry tells us that $P(A>B)=\frac {1-P_{\text {tie}}}2$ (understanding that $P_{\text {tie}}$ might be $0$).

Comment: why don't you include the details of how you used Bayes' rule so that the rest don't repeat your working?

Comment: If there is no further info about your approach then we cannot check it on correctness. It seems that your answer is correct because using symmetry we find $P(A>B)=\frac{49}{104}\sim0.471154$.

Comment: Basically, what I did is I exhausted all possibilities: P(A>B) = P(A|K)*P(K) + P(A|Q)*P(Q) + ...... + P(3|2)*P(2)

Answer (score 2):

You have  given your method in the comment box, but it is so much easier to use symmetry, as suggested by @drhab.

P(A = B) $= \dfrac3{51}$

so P(A $\neq$ B) = $1 - \dfrac3{51} = \dfrac{48}{51}$

and by symmetry, P(A > B) $= \dfrac12\dfrac{48}{51} = \dfrac{8}{17}$

Comment: I think we both made the same mistake and $P(A=B)=\frac3{51}$. Player B picks from "the rest".

Comment: @drhab: Thanks, corrected, that's what happens on missing the fine print !